# ASP.net Users ID tracking Google anayltic

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics

I would like to track the user id of the logged in users of my web app (asp.net) using Google analytic ?

Some idea how to get this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It believe this is not allowed by Google terms

From the GA Terms of Service: http://www.google.com/intl/en/analytics/tos.html

> PRIVACY . You will not (and will not allow any third party to) use the Service to track or collect personally identifiable information of
>   Internet users, nor will You (or will You allow any third party to)
>   associate any data gathered from Your website(s) (or such third
>   parties' website(s)) with any personally identifying information from
>   any source as part of Your use (or such third parties' use) of the
>   Service. You will have and abide by an appropriate privacy policy and
>   will comply with all applicable laws relating to the collection of
>   information from visitors to Your websites. You must post a privacy
>   policy and that policy must provide notice of your use of a cookie
>   that collects anonymous traffic data.